# Where to get free detailed historic data e.g. with interval <1 minute

Tags: web-services, data-mining, finance, stocks

I am looking for a free source of detailed stock data (bid and ask prices) with an interval of <1m. This is for testing out trading theories - therefore does not have to be live nor up to date. I would ideally like a source that could supply this data over a period of a day.

I know of and have used the Yahoo .csv 'API' for getting quotes; this offers a minimum interval of 1 day (as far as I can see) but I would like a source with an interval of <1 minute. For example, the Yahoo chart http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=BP.L#symbol=BP.L;range=1d actually has a very small interval between plotted prices; is there a way of leveraging this for example?

Comment: I've researched this before (some time ago) and found that most of the free services only reported the day's closing value; I couldn't find any that gave more details without paying for the data.

Answer (score 4):

There is no data source that will provide this. Exchanges increasingly make money by selling this data to clients. The economics of the exchanges pricing structure make it impossible for sites to give you this kind of data for free.

There are low cost sources of information ([iqfeed](http://www.iqfeed.net), [trading physics](http://tradingphysics.com/)). Since it seems like you are just playing around NASDAQ offers [samples](ftp://emi.nasdaq.com/ITCH) of its ITCH data which is the ultra low latency feed that HFT firms and many algo firms use.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing , There **is a way to get the Free Real time Market Data** by subscribing to https://alpaca.markets/
(Provider of Free Trading via API is US Markets). 
You can get https://polygon.io  data for free by using the API Key provided by Alpaca.
You can use their WebSocket and HTTP API to get the data.